# Comprehensive list of orginating_app_id in Google Drive logs: where?

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I'm a security engineer, and using a SIEM, we import Google Drive logs.

We run into a pretty consistent challenge when threat hunting with the following log/event fields:

events{}.name="download"
events{}.parameters{}.originating_app_id=""

`originating_app_id` seems to indicate that if a value for it is NOT present, it's a "real download," i.e. the user downloads the doc from the console in GDrive to their local. If `originating_app_id` == a number, it's a "download' event tied to a share. A true positive we know about is `originating_app_id=94....803` was tied to a in-chat share (Slack/Teams/similar, iirc but this may be inaccurate).

It looks like the only way to backtrace a `originating_app_id` in the logs is via this page, which then requires giving access of the Google API Explorer to our Google Drive: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/apps/get?apix_params=%7B%22appId%22%3A%22947318989803%22%7D

Three questions:

- Is there a comprehensive list of `originating_app_id / App name` somewhere that I can get. I feel like this used to exist until recently, but I might be mistaken.
- Is the Google API Explorer link the only way to tie `originating_app_id` to a name (edit for clarity: or pushing these IDs to the API ref'd as well, not just hitting the UI)
- Am I missing something

Difficulties this cause:

- very hard to determine the context of mass-"download" events. Scrubbing for the lack of a `originating_app_id` isn't a suitable approach though, as mass-shares have value to determine too.
- going to that link every time causes some inefficiencies, but I assume some automation could be done. having that translation natively in the google drive admin logs though would be better though.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alright found a way to do it, more or less:

- In the google admin page, go to Home -> API Controls -> Manage 3rd Party Apps ->
- This page has a list of all auth'd 3rd party apps in your workspace.
- the `originating_app_id` field doesn't seem searchable vs the `ID` field on that landing page, including trying wildcards.
- But: `originating_app_id` matches up to the first several digits of the `ID` for each app, up to a delimiter usually like `-` or `.`
- Export the App list via "Download App Info"
- Parse the `ID` fields to grab the `originating_app_id` part, build a csv of `App Name, ID`, etc etc
- Upload this to your SIEM, and bounce those `download` queries with their `originating_app_id` vs. this table in however your SIEM works (lookups for Splunk, etc).
- End: can cross-ref `originating_app_id` vs. the app's name.

I'm not sure if it's possible that you'd have an `originating_app_id` in your gdrive download logs beyond what's an auth'd app in Google Admin, but my guess is they'd match up or at least narrow down the investigation significantly.

Comment: Great contriubution!